# Мodification GGPLOT with weekly data

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is small example of my data set.This set contain weekly data about 52 weeks.You can see data with code below:

```
# CODE
 #Data

ARTIFICIALDATA<-dput(structure(list(week = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52), `2019 Series_1` = c(534.771929824561, 
350.385964912281, 644.736842105263, 366.561403508772, 455.649122807018, 
533.614035087719, 829.964912280702, 466.035087719298, 304.421052631579, 
549.473684210526, 649.719298245614, 537.964912280702, 484.982456140351, 
785.929824561404, 576.736842105263, 685.508771929824, 514.842105263158, 
464.491228070175, 608.245614035088, 756.701754385965, 431.859649122807, 
524.315789473684, 739.40350877193, 604.736842105263, 669.684210526316, 
570.491228070175, 641.649122807018, 649.298245614035, 664.210526315789, 
530.385964912281, 754.315789473684, 646.80701754386, 764.070175438596, 
421.333333333333, 470.842105263158, 774.245614035088, 752.842105263158, 
575.368421052632, 538.315789473684, 735.578947368421, 522, 862.561403508772, 
496.526315789474, 710.631578947368, 584.456140350877, 843.19298245614, 
563.473684210526, 568.456140350877, 625.368421052632, 768.912280701754, 
679.824561403509, 642.526315789474), `2020 Series_1` = c(294.350877192983, 
239.824561403509, 709.614035087719, 569.824561403509, 489.438596491228, 
561.964912280702, 808.456140350877, 545.157894736842, 589.649122807018, 
500.877192982456, 584.421052631579, 524.771929824561, 367.438596491228, 
275.228070175439, 166.736842105263, 58.2456140350878, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -52L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")))
```

So next steep is plot this data with ggplot2.So you can see my plot below

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = ARTIFICIALDATA, aes(x = week, y = `2019 Series_1`), color = "black") +
  geom_line(data = ARTIFICIALDATA, aes(x = week, y = `2020 Series_1`), color = "red",size=1,linetype=2) +
   xlab('Weeks') +
  ylab('US dolars')+
  theme(legend.position="top")

p
```

[image]

So this is how look like my plot, but here missing two things.First is legend (for 2019 Series_1 and  2020 Series_1) and x axis need to show values for all 52 weeks.So can anybody help me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Convert wide-to-long, then plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the answer:

```
library(tidyverse)

ARTIFICIALDATA_rec <- ARTIFICIALDATA %>% 
    gather(key = Year_indicator, value = time_series_value, -1)

your_plot <- ggplot(data = ARTIFICIALDATA_rec, aes(x = week, y = time_series_value, group = Year_indicator)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = Year_indicator)) +
    scale_x_continuous(name = "Week of the year", limits=c(0, 52), breaks=seq(0,52,2))
```

and this is the plot:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It would be simple to plot this if you have data in long format. Also you might control what to show on x-axis using `scale_x_continuous` by adding custom `breaks`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ARTIFICIALDATA %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -week, names_to = 'Series') %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x = week, y = value, color = Series) + geom_line() + 
    xlab('Weeks') +
    ylab('US dolars') +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(10, 40, 10), 52)) + 
    theme(legend.position="top")
```

[image]